# Collision detection bug in JS snake game

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

I'm trying to write a variation of Snake where the snake "bounces" off the walls.

It works most of the time, but occasionally the snake "escapes" and I can't figure out why. Initially I had the inequalities in the collison detection function set to strictly `<` or `>` which I thought was the cause of the problem, but I've changed them to `<=` and `>=` and the problem persists.

Can anyone explain why this is happening please? (You usually have to play for a minute or so before the snake escapes...)

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=500 style="display: block; border: 1px solid green; margin: auto;"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '30px Arial';

var HEIGHT = 500;
var WIDTH = 500;
var SEGMENT_WIDTH = 30;

var snakeVelocity = {
    i: 1,
    j: 0
};
var snakeArray = createSnake();

function createSnake() {
    var snakeArray = [];
    var length = 5; // Initial length of snake
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        snakeArray.push({
            x: i + 1, 
            y: 1
        });
    }
    return snakeArray;
}

function moveSnake(arr) {
    var head = arr.slice(-1)[0];
    var tail = arr[0];
    var newHead = arr.shift();

    // check for wall collision, which also updates velocity if needed
    snakeWallCollision(head);

    newHead.x = head.x + snakeVelocity.i;
    newHead.y = head.y +  + snakeVelocity.j;

    arr.push(newHead);
    return arr;
}

function snakeWallCollision(obj) {
    var collision = false;
    if (obj.x >= WIDTH / SEGMENT_WIDTH || obj.x <= 0) {
        snakeVelocity.i *= -1;
        collision = true;
    }
    if (obj.y >= HEIGHT / SEGMENT_WIDTH || obj.y <= 0) {
        snakeVelocity.j *= -1;
        collision = true;
    }
    return collision;
}

function drawSnake() {
    console.log(snakeArray[0]);
    for (var i = 0; i < snakeArray.length; i++) {
        var segment = snakeArray[i];
        ctx.fillText('S', segment.x * SEGMENT_WIDTH, segment.y * SEGMENT_WIDTH + 30);
    }
}

function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    moveSnake(snakeArray);
    drawSnake();
}

function checkKey(e) {

    e = e || window.event;

    if ([38, 40, 37, 39].includes(e.keyCode)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        snakeVelocity = {
            i: 0,
            j: -1
        };
    } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        snakeVelocity = {
            i: 0,
            j: 1
        };
    } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        snakeVelocity = {
            i: -1,
            j: 0
        };
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        snakeVelocity = {
            i: 1,
            j: 0
        };
    }
}
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
setInterval(update, 1000 / 20);
drawSnake();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs if you change direction away from the wall just  before you hit the wall.

Say for example the snake's head has just moved to x = 0 and moving left and the user keys right arrow just before the next update frame. Now the `snakeVelocity.i` is set to 1 away from the wall.

You then test the wall

```
if (obj.x >= WIDTH / SEGMENT_WIDTH || obj.x <= 0) {
    snakeVelocity.i *= -1; // negate the direction
                           // but the direction is already away from the
                           // wall due to user input. This will turn it back
                           // onto the wall
}
```

Same happens for up and down.

You need to have the collision test know what direction the snake is heading and then based on that test if that move will result in a collision.

Change the test function to find the next position the snake's head will be if allowed to move as its current state dictates. Only if that move results in the head being outside the bounds of the game do you change the direction.

```
function snakeWallCollision(head) {
    var x = head.x + snakeVelocity.i; // find out where the head will be 
    var y = head.y + snakeVelocity.j; // next frame
    if (x > WIDTH / SEGMENT_WIDTH || x < 0) {
        snakeVelocity.i *= -1;
        return true;
    }
    if (y > HEIGHT / SEGMENT_WIDTH || y < 0) {
        snakeVelocity.j *= -1;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That seems to fix it nicely. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you swap these lines around:

```
newHead.x = head.x + snakeVelocity.i;
newHead.y = head.y +  + snakeVelocity.j;

// check for wall collision, which also updates velocity if needed
snakeWallCollision(head);
```

Comment: This looks like it should work if you use `snakeWallCollision(newHead);`, but I think because the `newHead` values are committed the snake still escapes...

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that if the user presses a key synchronized with your `collision check` the directions changes twice and the snake goes beyond the wall.

Maybe this one helps you out (i added a test variable `USER_ACTION` to check if the user has pressed the key and if so, don't do the `collision check`):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '30px Arial';

var HEIGHT = 500;
var WIDTH = 500;
var SEGMENT_WIDTH = 30;
var USER_ACTION = false;

var snakeVelocity = {
    i: 1,
    j: 0
};
var snakeArray = createSnake();

function createSnake() {
    var snakeArray = [];
    var length = 5; // Initial length of snake
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        snakeArray.push({
            x: i + 1,
            y: 1
        });
    }
    return snakeArray;
}

function moveSnake(arr) {
    var head = arr.slice(-1)[0];
    var tail = arr[0];
    var newHead = arr.shift();

    // check for wall collision, which also updates velocity if needed
    snakeWallCollision(head);

    newHead.x = head.x + snakeVelocity.i;
    newHead.y = head.y + +snakeVelocity.j;

    arr.push(newHead);
    return arr;
}

function snakeWallCollision(obj) {
    if (!USER_ACTION) {
        var collision = false;
        if (obj.x >= WIDTH / SEGMENT_WIDTH || obj.x <= 0) {
            snakeVelocity.i *= -1;
            collision = true;
        }
        if (obj.y >= HEIGHT / SEGMENT_WIDTH || obj.y <= 0) {
            snakeVelocity.j *= -1;
            collision = true;
        }
    } else {
        USER_ACTION = false;
    }
    return collision;
}

function drawSnake() {
    console.log(snakeArray[0]);
    for (var i = 0; i < snakeArray.length; i++) {
        var segment = snakeArray[i];
        ctx.fillText('S', segment.x * SEGMENT_WIDTH, segment.y * SEGMENT_WIDTH + 30);
    }
}

function update() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    moveSnake(snakeArray);
    drawSnake();
}

function checkKey(e) {
    USER_ACTION = true;
    e = e || window.event;

    if ([38, 40, 37, 39].includes(e.keyCode)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    if (e.keyCode == '38') {
        snakeVelocity = {
            i: 0,
            j: -1
        };
    } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
        snakeVelocity = {
            i: 0,
            j: 1
        };
    } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
        snakeVelocity = {
            i: -1,
            j: 0
        };
    } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
        snakeVelocity = {
            i: 1,
            j: 0
        };
    }
}
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
setInterval(update, 1000 / 20);
drawSnake();
```

Comment: Sadly the issue persists with this version. Thanks anyway.